# RestSharp JSON Array deserialization

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization

I launch this RestSharp query in JSON format:

```
var response = restClient.Execute<Report>(request);
```

The response I get contains this data

```
[
    {
        "Columns":
        [
            {"Name":"CameraGuid","Type":"Guid"},
            {"Name":"ArchiveSourceGuid","Type":"Guid"},
            {"Name":"StartTime","Type":"DateTime"},
            {"Name":"EndTime","Type":"DateTime"},
            {"Name":"TimeZone","Type":"String"},
            {"Name":"Capabilities","Type":"UInt32"}
        ],
        "Rows":
        [
            [
                "00000001-0000-babe-0000-00408c71be50",
                "3782fe37-6748-4d36-b258-49ed6a79cd6d",
                "2013-11-27T17:52:00Z",
                "2013-11-27T18:20:55.063Z",
                "Eastern Standard Time",
                2147483647
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into this group of classes:

```
public class Report
{
    public List<ReportResult> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ReportResult
{
    public List<ColumnField> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<RowResult>   Rows { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class RowResult
{
    public List<string> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, the result data is null and I get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

I cannot figure out what is wrong here.
I little help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
var response = restClient.Execute<List<ReportResult>>(request);
```

**EDIT**

You should also change `ReportResult` to:

```
public class ReportResult
{
  public List<ColumnField> Columns { get; set; }
  public List<List<string>>   Rows { get; set; }
}
```

and you can get rid of `Report` and `RowResult`.

Comment: I think he'll also have a problem due to the `Elements` property. `Rows` should be a `List<string>` (unless you can tell JSON.net that's how it is, maybe via attributes).

Comment: Good catch, `Rows` should be `List<List<string>>` though

Comment: Using IList<ReportResult> gives my a compilation error:

Error CS0310: The type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<ReportResult>' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter `T' in the generic type or method `ExecuteRequest<T>(RestSharp.RestRequest)' (CS0310)

Comment: Change it to `List<ReportResult>`, I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Also, trying the List<List<string>> gives my the same error (unable to cast...)

Comment: Reda, you made my day!  Worked like a charm.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way by creating wrapper class:

```
public class ThirdPartySuggesters : List<ThirdPartySuggester> {}
var response = client.Execute<ThirdPartySuggesters>(request);
```